# How to intersect array only if they exists

Tags: php, ajax

I need to make an intersection of three arrays for an ajax autocompletion select input, so sometimes one or more array are empty and array_intersect function returns me an error : `array_intersect(): Argument #1 is not an array`

```
$output['Family'] = array_intersect($temp['VernNamesSelected']['Family'], $temp['GenusSelected']['Family'], $temp['SpeciesSelected']['Family']);
$output['Genus'] = array_intersect($temp['VernNamesSelected']['Genus'], $temp['FamiliesSelected']['Genus'], $temp['SpeciesSelected']['Genus']);
$output['Species'] = array_intersect($temp['VernNamesSelected']['Species'], $temp['FamiliesSelected']['Species'], $temp['GenusSelected']['Species']);
```

Is there a way to do an intersection without writing a lot of dirty conditions to avoid the errors ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used stacked ternary operators to solve my issue, but i'm still opened to a more elegant way of doing this

```
$output['Family'] = (isset($temp['VernNamesSelected']['Family']) && isset($temp['GenusSelected']['Family']) && isset($temp['SpeciesSelected']['Family']) ? array_intersect($temp['VernNamesSelected']['Family'],$temp['GenusSelected']['Family'],$temp['SpeciesSelected']['Family']) :
    (isset($temp['VernNamesSelected']['Family']) && isset($temp['GenusSelected']['Family']) && !isset($temp['SpeciesSelected']['Family']) ? array_intersect($temp['VernNamesSelected']['Family'],$temp['GenusSelected']['Family']) :
    (isset($temp['VernNamesSelected']['Family']) && !isset($temp['GenusSelected']['Family']) && isset($temp['SpeciesSelected']['Family']) ? array_intersect($temp['VernNamesSelected']['Family'],$temp['SpeciesSelected']['Family']) :
    (!isset($temp['VernNamesSelected']['Family']) && isset($temp['GenusSelected']['Family']) && isset($temp['SpeciesSelected']['Family']) ? array_intersect($temp['GenusSelected']['Family'],$temp['SpeciesSelected']['Family']) :
    (isset($temp['VernNamesSelected']['Family']) && !isset($temp['GenusSelected']['Family']) && !isset($temp['SpeciesSelected']['Family']) ? $temp['VernNamesSelected']['Family'] :
    (!isset($temp['VernNamesSelected']['Family']) && isset($temp['GenusSelected']['Family']) && !isset($temp['SpeciesSelected']['Family']) ? $temp['GenusSelected']['Family'] :
    (!isset($temp['VernNamesSelected']['Family']) && !isset($temp['GenusSelected']['Family']) && isset($temp['SpeciesSelected']['Family']) ? $temp['SpeciesSelected']['Family'] :
    NULL)))))));

$output['Genus'] = (isset($temp['VernNamesSelected']['Genus']) && isset($temp['GenusSelected']['Genus']) && isset($temp['SpeciesSelected']['Genus']) ? array_intersect($temp['VernNamesSelected']['Genus'],$temp['GenusSelected']['Genus'],$temp['SpeciesSelected']['Genus']) :
        (isset($temp['VernNamesSelected']['Genus']) && isset($temp['GenusSelected']['Genus']) && !isset($temp['SpeciesSelected']['Genus']) ? array_intersect($temp['VernNamesSelected']['Genus'],$temp['GenusSelected']['Genus']) :
        (isset($temp['VernNamesSelected']['Genus']) && !isset($temp['GenusSelected']['Genus']) && isset($temp['SpeciesSelected']['Genus']) ? array_intersect($temp['VernNamesSelected']['Genus'],$temp['SpeciesSelected']['Genus']) :
        (!isset($temp['VernNamesSelected']['Genus']) && isset($temp['GenusSelected']['Genus']) && isset($temp['SpeciesSelected']['Genus']) ? array_intersect($temp['GenusSelected']['Genus'],$temp['SpeciesSelected']['Genus']) :
        (isset($temp['VernNamesSelected']['Genus']) && !isset($temp['GenusSelected']['Genus']) && !isset($temp['SpeciesSelected']['Genus']) ? $temp['VernNamesSelected']['Genus'] :
        (!isset($temp['VernNamesSelected']['Genus']) && isset($temp['GenusSelected']['Genus']) && !isset($temp['SpeciesSelected']['Genus']) ? $temp['GenusSelected']['Genus'] :
        (!isset($temp['VernNamesSelected']['Genus']) && !isset($temp['GenusSelected']['Genus']) && isset($temp['SpeciesSelected']['Genus']) ? $temp['SpeciesSelected']['Genus'] :
        NULL)))))));

$output['Species'] = (isset($temp['VernNamesSelected']['Species']) && isset($temp['GenusSelected']['Species']) && isset($temp['SpeciesSelected']['Species']) ? array_intersect($temp['VernNamesSelected']['Species'],$temp['GenusSelected']['Species'],$temp['SpeciesSelected']['Species']) :
        (isset($temp['VernNamesSelected']['Species']) && isset($temp['GenusSelected']['Species']) && !isset($temp['SpeciesSelected']['Species']) ? array_intersect($temp['VernNamesSelected']['Species'],$temp['GenusSelected']['Species']) :
        (isset($temp['VernNamesSelected']['Species']) && !isset($temp['GenusSelected']['Species']) && isset($temp['SpeciesSelected']['Species']) ? array_intersect($temp['VernNamesSelected']['Species'],$temp['SpeciesSelected']['Species']) :
        (!isset($temp['VernNamesSelected']['Species']) && isset($temp['GenusSelected']['Species']) && isset($temp['SpeciesSelected']['Species']) ? array_intersect($temp['GenusSelected']['Species'],$temp['SpeciesSelected']['Species']) :
        (isset($temp['VernNamesSelected']['Species']) && !isset($temp['GenusSelected']['Species']) && !isset($temp['SpeciesSelected']['Species']) ? $temp['VernNamesSelected']['Species'] :
        (!isset($temp['VernNamesSelected']['Species']) && isset($temp['GenusSelected']['Species']) && !isset($temp['SpeciesSelected']['Species']) ? $temp['GenusSelected']['Species'] :
        (!isset($temp['VernNamesSelected']['Species']) && !isset($temp['GenusSelected']['Species']) && isset($temp['SpeciesSelected']['Species']) ? $temp['SpeciesSelected']['Species'] :
        NULL)))))));
```

Answer (score 1):

Check with the function `isset` and test with `is_array` wether the object is an array.

For example this

```
if(isset($temp['VernNamesSelected']['Family']) && is_array($temp['VernNamesSelected']['Family']) && isset($temp['GenusSelected']['Family']) && is_array($temp['GenusSelected']['Family']) && isset($temp['SpeciesSelected']['Family']) && is_array($temp['SpeciesSelected']['Family'])) {
    $output['Family'] = array_intersect($temp['VernNamesSelected']['Family'], $temp['GenusSelected']['Family'], $temp['SpeciesSelected']['Family']);
}
....
```